# How to slide multiple UIViews with same speed

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uikit

I have two views in my storyboard and I'm sliding them using the height constraint just through the following codes.

ViewOne with 150.0 height after sliding

```
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.con_ViewOneHeight.constant = 150.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

ViewTwo with 1000.0 height after sliding

```
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.con_ViewTwoHeight.constant = 1000.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

Both animation happens within 0.3 seconds but the second view's animation happens with more speed than the first one. I understand that it is happening because time is same but how can we calculate time for each view having same speed?

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you are asking... are both views the same *starting* height? So, you want them to size at the same "speed" until they are both 150-pts, and then continue growing ViewTwo at the same relative speed until it is 1000-pts?

Comment: @DonMag the initial size is 0 for both views

Comment: So, the answer to the rest of my question is "Yes"? You want them both to expand at the same speed till they reach 150-pts, and then you want ViewTwo to continue at the same speed to 1000-pts?

Comment: Starting from 0 I need first View to be grown up to 150 and the second View up to 1000 with same speed

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a desired speed in seconds/points and then compute time for each height :

```
let speed = 0.3/150.0 // 0.3 seconds for 150 points
let heightForViewOne = 150.0 
let timeForViewOne = heightForViewOne * speed // (=0.3s)
let heightForViewTwo = 1000.0
let timeForViewTwo = heightForViewTwo * speed // (=2s)
```

Then use timeForViewxxx and heightForViewxxx in the animate call

Comment: I have tried this but as a result the speed becomes very slower than the first view

Comment: Can you try using the difference between before and after heights for each view ? ie abs(heightAfterOne-heightBeforeOne)

Answer (score 0):

To make the math simple, suppose you want viewOne to go from Zero to 100, and viewTwo height to go from Zero to 200...

If you set the Animation duration for viewOne to 1-second, the duration for viewTwo would need to be 2-seconds.

So, you can do it like this:

```
    // duration for viewOne animation
    let dur1 = 0.5
    // calculate needed duration for viewTwo animation
    let dur2 = (1000.0 / 150.0) * dur1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: dur1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.con_ViewOneHeight.constant = 150.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: dur2, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.con_ViewTwoHeight.constant = 1000.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Here's a working example. Tap anywhere in the view to expand viewOne (blue) and viewTwo (red). Each tap will reset and re-run the animation:

```
class DoubleGrowViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewOne = UIView()
    let viewTwo = UIView()
    
    var con_ViewOneHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var con_ViewTwoHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        viewOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        viewOne.backgroundColor = .blue
        viewTwo.backgroundColor = .red
        
        view.addSubview(viewOne)
        view.addSubview(viewTwo)
        
        con_ViewOneHeight = viewOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        con_ViewTwoHeight = viewTwo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            viewOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            viewOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            viewOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            con_ViewOneHeight,
            
            viewTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            viewTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewOne.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            viewTwo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            con_ViewTwoHeight,
            
        ])

        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doAnim(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }
    
    @objc func doAnim(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer?) -> Void {

        // if the animation is running, we'll
        //  stop it
        //  reset view height constraints to 0
        //  re-start the animation (async)
        if con_ViewOneHeight.constant != 0.0 {
            viewOne.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            viewTwo.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            con_ViewOneHeight.constant = 0.0
            con_ViewTwoHeight.constant = 0.0
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.doAnim(nil)
            }
            return
        }
        
        // duration for viewOne animation
        let dur1 = 0.5
        // calculate needed duration for viewTwo animation
        let dur2 = (1000.0 / 150.0) * dur1

        UIView.animate(withDuration: dur1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.con_ViewOneHeight.constant = 150.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: dur2, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.con_ViewTwoHeight.constant = 1000.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
    
}
```